How to decrease the size of sub/super script latex
How do I globally change the size of subscripts and superscripts? (I would like to make them smaller)

I’m pretty sure that you wouldn’t like the result when you saw it. Trust me, a lot of thought and work has gone into choosing the default subscript and superscript sizes in TeX.

What I dislike about current sizing is that it sometimes requires extra line space to be put in. I'd like uniform line spacing with little positive leading, and so I need to decrease the size of scripts. I've tried it locally with scalarel, liked the result, but it would be far preferable to do this globally.

The only other alternative I can think of is to increase the height of the subscript and decrease the height of the superscript, which I also don't know how to do.

I actually agree that this problem exists, but I disagree with the solution you propose. First and foremost, if you don’t already do this, try your best to avoid large structures in sub- and superscripts. For instance, write x^{2/3} instead of x^{\frac{2}{3}}, and use \exp(...) instead of e^{...} for large expressions. Or try to write such things in display math rather than inline math. In the cases where none of these tricks work, you can avoid extra long lines by doing \smash{$...$}. Quite often, it will turn out that there actually was enough room on the line for the expression.

I appreciate the suggestions. Unfortunately, these aren't applicable in at least some of my use cases. In Algebraic Geometry, you'll often get expressions you want to keep inline like $\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x),x}$ which could really benefit from increasing the vertical height of subscript or decreasing the size.

Try \smash{$\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,x}$}.

It doesn't help with the height. Even if you wouldn't recommend changing the other variables, how would you go about it?

Which font are you using? With Computer Modern, I don’t see any increased height of the line at all.

Baskerville and MTPro lite. It might be a bad example, a better one would be $\Omega^{1}{\mathcal{O}{X}(U)/\mathcal{O}_{V}(Y)}$ Either way, it also looks quite cluttered due to how far down the subscript descends.

But anyway, also have a look at this answer. As for the example you provide, it actually looks fine with Computer Modern when I try it. Also, sometimes, in complicated math, simpler is cleaner. Consider writing simply \Omega^{1} if the sheaf or ring is obvious from the context. Your readers will appreciate this, too. Also, I’m a big fan of writing \mathcal{O}(U) instead of \mathcal{O}_{X}(U).

Thank you very much! Only problem is that it doesn't seem to be compatible with specifying the font size of ordinary text in the document class.

I mean, it doesn’t matter much if you use \mathcal{O}_{X} or the restricted sheaf \mathcal{O}_{U}. You will get the same result. There is usually only one \mathcal{O} for a given subscheme.

With luatex and Unicode math you can overwrite some font parameters to achieve smaller subscripts, and others to move them up and/or down differently.

$\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,x}$ fits within baseline spacing using the default fonts but adding a bit of extra height and depth does show an example that disturbs baseline spacing

\documentclass{article}

\showoutput\showboxdepth3
\begin{document}


Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Aaaa $\hat\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,y}$ bbb ccc
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Aaaa $\hat\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,y}$ bbb ccc
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 

\end{document}

You can use smaller script and scriptscript size for 10pt base font:

Which has even spacing (but unreadable subscripts)
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput\showboxdepth3

\DeclareMathSizes{10pt}{10pt}{4}{3}
\begin{document}


Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Aaaa $\hat\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,y}$ bbb ccc
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Aaaa $\hat\Omega_{X_{k}/\kappa(x)\,y}$ bbb ccc
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 
Some text text text text text text text 

\end{document}


Perhaps you might want to show what happens if you \smash it. Also, isn’t \hat{\Omega} the recommended syntax nowadays?

@Gaussler \smash can work sometimes (but in general may cause over-printing so hard to recommend as a general solution, and it doesn't directly answer the question in the title) as for \hat{} you don't need nowadays the recommendation hasn't changed it has always been to use braces, but sometimes I am rebellious

That’s fine, rebel as much as you want. After Brexit, it won’t hurt the rest of us anymore.

@ David Carlisle how would I do this for 11pt font. It doesn't seem to scale?

@NoahLaikin the default for 11pt is \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}  so \makeatletter\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{5}{4}\makeatother (note \@xipt is  10.95pt not 11pt (so you can use 10.95pt if you don't like the @

Does this work with different fonts?

@NoahLaikin yes, although some font packages adjust it so  you need to set it after that
